# I need help finding the solution about $z=0$ of the following differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, general-relativity

The differential equation is $$\frac{d^2g}{dz^2}-\frac{l(l+1)}{z(z-1)}g=0.$$

After using the Frobenius method I have gotten to indicial roots $r=1,0$. The recursion formula for $r=0$ is $$n(n+1)c_{n+1} = [n(n-1)-l(l+1)]c_n.$$

And for $r = 1$ the recursion is $$(n+1)(n+2)c_{n+1}=[k(k+1)-l(l+1)]c_n.$$

Now my problem is that I cannot obtain the first independent solution whose first few terms are $$u_0=z, u_1=z(1-z), u_2=z(z-1)(2z-1), \dots,$$

where $$g_1(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n^l u_l(z).$$

I will be very grateful to anyone that can explain how to obtain the above solution.

Comment: What you have posted is not an equation. Further, if you mean that to be set equal to zero, then it is separable.

Comment: @rogerl. Are you sure that it would be separable ? It is $g''(z)$, not $g'(z)$

Comment: @claudeleibovici you're right, I didn't read carefully enough.

Comment: @rogerl, I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method to solve the equation is shown below. This involves the $_2\text{F}_1$ hypergeometric function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html

[image]

Comment: @Noor Aslam : I am on the verge to leave for several days. Sorry, I have not enough time to search for the second independent solution.

Comment: sir can you explain the series solution obtained for the u(z)
 using Frobiniuos method and also i have problem in the transformation you used to change the equation into hypergeometric form
how can i guess the transformation

Comment: Sorry, actually I have not enough time to edit an answer which requires a long typing. About your question of guess : There is no guess, you try various transformations until finding one which leads to an equation simpler to solve. In the present case, by luck, a very simple transformation leads to the known hypergeometric ODE. Of course this method of search doesn't always succeed.